# Why is the Cech nerve $C(U)$ of a surjective map $U\to X$ weakly equivalent to $X$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $f:U\to X$ be a surjective map of sets and
$$
...U\times_XU\times_XU \substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow \\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow}
U\times_X\times U  \substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex]
                       \\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow}
U
$$
the simplicial set given by its [Cech nerve](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+nerve#definition) $C(U)$. When I consider $X$ as a discrete simplicial set, there is a map $f':C(U)\to X$ of simplicial sets.

> Why is $f'$ a weak equivalence?

I see that $colim(U\times_X\times U \substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex]
                       \\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow} U)\cong X$ and that $\pi_0(C(U))$ is that colimit but I don't understand why there is a weak equivalence between the simplicial set $C(U)$ and the discrete one $\pi_0(C(U))$? Is $C(U)$ itself discrete? I don't think so.

**Update:** Is $C(U)$ weakly equivalent to $\pi_0(C(U))$ even for a non-surjective map $f:U\to X$ of sets?

Answer (score 1):

Using the axiom of choice, $f : U \to X$ is a *split* epimorphism, and so the Čech nerve has an extra degeneracy. As usual, this extra degeneracy can be used to construct a *homotopy equivalence* between the Čech nerve of $f$ and $X$; and of course, every homotopy equivalence is in particular a weak homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Is it also possible to say that $C(U)$ is weakly equivalent to $\pi_0(C(U))$ for a general map of sets $f:U\to X$ which is not an epimorphism? I need the surjectivity for $\pi_0(C(U))\cong X$ already.

Comment: Factor the map as a surjection followed by an inclusion; the Čech nerve of the surjection part is the same as the Čech nerve of the original map.

Comment: I would like to understand the statement about the homotopy equivalence. I see this on [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/019P). Seemingly the only place that $f\circ s=\operatorname{id}$ is used is to define the displayed morphism, and this is not used to check that these morphisms give rise to a homotopy (I would like to ask whether this is true), i.e. arbitrary $g^0,g^1$, as long as these maps are well defined, they will fit into a homotopy.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $f': C(U)\to X$ is an acyclic fibration. Using the fact that $C(U)$ is a groupoid, it suffices to verify two conditions.